# How to use pandas to get several binary features effectively?

Tags: python, pandas

My data is like that

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.Series(data = ["a b", "b c", "a b c"])
```

And I want to transfer it to binary features like that

```
  a b c
0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1
2 1 1 1
```

What's the most effective way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Found the solution, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256415/problems-with-a-binary-one-hot-one-of-k-coding-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
0      a b
1      b c
2    a b c
dtype: object

print data.str.get_dummies(sep=' ')
   a  b  c
0  1  1  0
1  0  1  1
2  1  1  1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's just exactly what I am looking for!